# Azure Data Factory V2 Dynamic Content

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Long story short, I have a data dump that is too large for an azure function. So we are using Data Factory. 
I have tasked another function to generate an access token for an API and output it as part of a json. I would like to set that token to a variable within the pipeline. So far I have this:
[image]

I'm attempting to use the Dynamic Content "language" to set the variable:

```
@activity('Get_Token').output
```

I'd like something like pythons:

```
token = data.get('data', {}).get('access_token', '')
```

As a secondary question, my next step is to use this token to call an API while iterating over another output, so perhaps this exact step can be added into the ForEach?

Comment: `@activity('Get_Token').output` is correct. I don't get your point about `token = data.get('data', {}).get('access_token', '')`. Would you please give more details or statemetns?

Comment: I would like to set the variable to a value within the json, not the json in its entirety.

Comment: Output is JSON, so it should something like @activity('Get_Token').output.YourPropertyName or @activity('Get_Token').output.value.YourPropertyName

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a test soon.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the variable should be `@activity('Get token').output.data.access_token` as others have indicated but, as you've guessed, there's no need to assign a variable if you only need it within the foreach.  You can access any predecessor output from that successor activity.  Here's how to use the token while iterating over another output:

1. Let's say your function also outputs `listOfThings` as an array
   within the `data` key. Then you can set the foreach activity to
   iterate over `@activity('Get token').output.data.listOfThings`.
2. Inside the foreach you will have (let's say) a Copy activity with a
   REST dataset as the source.  Configure the REST **linked service**
   with anonymous auth ...
3. ... then you'll find a field called *Additional
   Headers* in the REST **dataset** where you can create a key `Authorization`
   with value as above, `Basic @activity('Get token').output.data.access_token`
4. The thing that you said you want to iterate over (in the `listOfThings` JSON array) can be referenced inside the foreach activity with
   `@item()` (or, if it's a member of an item in the listOfThings
   iterable then it would be `@item().myMember`)

To make #4 explicit for anyone else arriving here:

- If listOfThings looks like this, `listOfThings: [ "thing1", "thing2", ...]`
- for example, `filenames: ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", ...]`
- then `@item()` becomes `file1.txt` etc.

**whereas**

- If listOfThings looks like this, `listOfThings: [ {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2" ... }, {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2" ... }, ...]`
- for example. `filenames: [ {"folder":"folder1", "filename":"file1.txt"}, {"folder":"folder2", "filename":"file2.txt"}, ... ]`
- then `@item().filename` becomes `file1.txt` etc.

Comment: Thank you, this was a very well detailed answer!